# OCMock stub isSelected property

Tags: ios, unit-testing, ocmock

I am trying to stub the selected property on `UIButton`. The getter is defined as:

```
@property (nonatomic, getter=isSelected) BOOL selected;
```

My stub looks like this:

```
[[[button stub] andReturnValue:OCMOCK_VALUE(TRUE)] isSelected];
```

I receive the following error when I run the test:

```
Return value does not match method signature; signature declares 'c' but value is 'i'.
```

I think this is something to do with the `getter=isSelected` part but not sure what's going on

Is it possible to stub this type of getter?

Comment: For this particular case, wouldn't be better to use a real UIButton and set the selected property normally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is annoying. The problem is that passing `TRUE` to `OCMOCK_VALUE` results in the creation of a value of type integer. The message you get is OCMock's way of saying that the method/property you want to stub is a boolean but you provided an integer.

You can force the creation of a an actual boolean value with either of the following:

```
[[[button stub] andReturnValue:OCMOCK_VALUE((BOOL){TRUE})] isSelected];

[[[button stub] andReturnValue:@YES] isSelected];
```

By the way, a similar problem occurs with different number types but unfortunately fixing this in OCMock isn't trivial. See here for example: https://github.com/erikdoe/ocmock/pull/58.

Comment: By the way, with a recent change to OCMock (https://github.com/erikdoe/ocmock/pull/115) this problem should not occur any more.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer my question but incase anyone else stumbles across this problem a workaround is to do a partial mock of an actual instance of `UIButton`.

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] init];
button.selected = TRUE;
id mockButton = [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:button];
```